# LinExpr() type in gurobi to create constraint - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, solver, gurobi

I'm learning how to use gurobi. I hope someone can help me on this.

I have a variable of type **LinExpr()**
Lets call it: **a**

After some operation I end up with that expression:

> gurobi.LinExpr: X1  + -0.18 X1010  + -0.72 X11  + -0.18 X1011  + -0.72 X12  + -0.18 X1012  + -0.72 X13  + -0.18 X1013  + X2  + -0.72 X1000  + -0.18 X1010  + -0.72 X1001  + -0.18 X1011  + -0.72 X1002  + -0.18 X1012  + -0.18 X1013

Can i create a constraint by doing for example:

```
m.addConstr(a==0.5)
```

?

Furthermore my actual LP model always send out **Infeasible model**.
Is there efficient ways to debug code which use gurobi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if `a` is a `LinExpr()` you can do `m.addConstr(a==0.5)`

If your LP is being classified as infeasible, you can try computing an Irreducible Inconsistent Subsystem ([IIS](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.6/reference-manual/py_model_computeiis)). This is a subset of constraints that are infeasible. You can usually use an IIS to find out what combination of constraints in your model are causing it to be infeasible. It is a useful debugging tool.

To compute an IIS in Python do:

```
model.computeIIS()
model.write('mymodel.ilp')
```

This will write out a file named mymodel.ilp that contains the IIS.